# Why "Failed to define class" WARN from server startup?

Tags: java, logging, jboss, liquibase

When I execute liquibase in JBoss I get the following WARN but everything is updated correctly:

```
12:32:01,499 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) Failed to define class liquibase.sdk.watch.WatchCommand$DynamicContentHandler in Module "deployment.WebStories.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link liquibase/sdk/watch/WatchCommand$DynamicContentHandler (Module "deployment.WebStories.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:407) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:254) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:518) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.loadClass(DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.java:358) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.loadImplementationsInJar(DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.java:406) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.findAllClasses(DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.java:226) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.find(DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.java:116) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.findImplementations(DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.java:84) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.findClassesImpl(ServiceLocator.java:202) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.findClasses(ServiceLocator.java:177) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.<init>(DatabaseFactory.java:25) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.getInstance(DatabaseFactory.java:40) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.integration.servlet.LiquibaseServletListener.executeUpdate(LiquibaseServletListener.java:211) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.integration.servlet.LiquibaseServletListener.contextInitialized(LiquibaseServletListener.java:106) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/AbstractHandler
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:338) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:402) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler from [Module "deployment.WebStories.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    ... 36 more

12:32:01,532 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) Failed to define class liquibase.sdk.supplier.database.AllDatabaseTypes in Module "deployment.WebStories.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link liquibase/sdk/supplier/database/AllDatabaseTypes (Module "deployment.WebStories.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:407) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:254) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:518) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.loadClass(DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.java:358) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.loadImplementationsInJar(DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.java:406) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.findAllClasses(DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.java:226) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.find(DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.java:116) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.findImplementations(DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.java:84) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.findClassesImpl(ServiceLocator.java:202) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.findClasses(ServiceLocator.java:177) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.<init>(DatabaseFactory.java:25) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.getInstance(DatabaseFactory.java:40) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.integration.servlet.LiquibaseServletListener.executeUpdate(LiquibaseServletListener.java:211) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.integration.servlet.LiquibaseServletListener.contextInitialized(LiquibaseServletListener.java:106) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/experimental/theories/ParameterSupplier
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:338) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:402) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.experimental.theories.ParameterSupplier from [Module "deployment.WebStories.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    ... 36 more

12:32:01,546 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) Failed to define class liquibase.sdk.supplier.database.AllDatabases in Module "deployment.WebStories.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link liquibase/sdk/supplier/database/AllDatabases (Module "deployment.WebStories.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:407) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:254) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:518) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.loadClass(DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.java:358) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.loadImplementationsInJar(DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.java:406) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.findAllClasses(DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.java:226) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.find(DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.java:116) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.findImplementations(DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.java:84) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.findClassesImpl(ServiceLocator.java:202) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.findClasses(ServiceLocator.java:177) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.<init>(DatabaseFactory.java:25) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.getInstance(DatabaseFactory.java:40) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.integration.servlet.LiquibaseServletListener.executeUpdate(LiquibaseServletListener.java:211) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at liquibase.integration.servlet.LiquibaseServletListener.contextInitialized(LiquibaseServletListener.java:106) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/experimental/theories/ParameterSupplier
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:338) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:402) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.experimental.theories.ParameterSupplier from [Module "deployment.WebStories.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    ... 36 more

12:32:01,652 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) INFO 23/10/14 12:32: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock

12:32:02,336 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) INFO 23/10/14 12:32: liquibase: Reading from public.databasechangelog

12:32:02,383 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) INFO 23/10/14 12:32: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
```

Any stacktrace in the server startup is considered an error, despite it is marked as a WARN, INFO or NOTHING.

Why does that happen?
What can I do to remove this stacktrace from the server startup?

Comment: As far as I can tell deployment.WebStories.war is missing, which likely means your jsps either aren't being compiled properly or it hasn't been deployed. Try rebuilding the project and deploying it again?

Comment: The project is properly deployed using JBoss Tools and eclipse. There is only one reference to this issue I could find: http://www.hascode.com/2014/07/java-ee-7-database-migrations-with-liquibase-and-wildfly/#Classloader_Issues

In the version 3.1.1 this does not occur.

Comment: That does look exactly like your problem, though switching to an older version doesn't seem very appealing either.

Comment: Yes, I want to understand just why that happens, because I am not familiarized with liquibase internals. If I don't get a proper responde here I will try to open a ticket into their bug tracker (if there is one, cause I have just started using liquibase =/)

Comment: Is this happening when you deploy from Eclipse or is it a normal deployment? Your deployment seems to have dependencies on JUnit and an internal Eclipse class that supports Jetty

Comment: Hi Steve, thx for commenting. After deploying with eclipse and JBoss Tools, this error occurs upon starting the server. I have not tried deploying without eclipse. I am using JUnit for tests only in my app.

Comment: It only happens when I add the version 3.2.0 of liquibase and up. 3.1.1 is ok, no WARN happens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Liquibase internally scans your classpath using your classloader to find classes that may be Liquibase extensions. Part of that scanning is hitting a few classes that are bundled with the liquibase jar but are not part of the normal `liquibase update` process.

In particular, it is checking code that displays the database and liquibase state that can be helpful in demos and troubleshooting and other code that can be used for testing extensions.

These non-standard use classes reference additional dependencies such as jetty and junit and which are normally not available in production environments and so Liquibase expects some ClassNotFoundExceptions and DEBUG-level logs them, moves on, and updates correctly as you are seeing.

In your case, it appears that the JBoss classloader has an additional feature to log at WARN level any ClassNotFoundExceptions it runs into throwing it up the chain to the point that Liquibase ignores it.

A future release of Liquibase will better split between the "tools" codebase and the "standard" codebase, but for now your options would be:

- Include the missing dependencies in your classpath (jetty and junit based in your stacktrace)
- Create enough of a stub class named the same as the referenced jetty and junit classes in order to make the class loader happy.
- Set the log level for "org.jboss.modules" to ERROR in order to not log WARN-level logs

Comment: I am interested in `A future release of Liquibase will better split between the "tools" codebase and the "standard" codebase`. If that is the case, I am willing to wait a new version to fix this instead of messing with my environment. For now I am using version 3.1.1, which at least does not throw any WARN in my console. By the way, is this going to be fixed soon or something very low priority? This information may influence the tradeoff to update liquibase and change my environment to be compatible or wait for a new version.

Comment: I'm hoping around January 2015, but it will depend on how development goes.

Comment: Test with liquibase 3.4.2 and Wildfly 9.0.2. Problem solved

Answer (score 6):

I have used this class, which very probably will ***not*** work on jetty, but on all other servers (tomcat, jboss/wildfly, weblogic, websphere, glassfish, tomee, ...)
I've tested it on tomcat and wildfly.

```
package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler;

/**
 * Workaround for this issues in liquibase.
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530677/why-failed-to-define-class-warn-from-server-startup.
 * https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2024.
 *
 * @author cilap
 *
 */
public class AbstractHandler {

   /**
    * Trace to logfile the workaround.
    */
   public AbstractHandler() {
      System.err.println("Workaround for http://stackoverflow.com/questions    /26530677/why-failed-to-define-class-warn-from-server-startup and "
            + "https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2024");
      System.err.println("please remove this from the repository as soon as the bug is fixed on liquibase.");
   }
}
```

This is not nice but it works.

**Edit1:**

The Classloader is searching for the Class `org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler`
Since we are not on the Jetty, the class cannot be found by the classloader.

One option would be to add the jetty jar file into the tomcat or the wildfly, **BUT** this will very probably cause issues on tomcat/wildfly, since they implement also expected interfaces and classes which both, Jetty and Wildfly/tomcat provide. 
To avoid this - until it is fixed by Liquibase - you have to provide the Classloader a dummy implementation of AbstractHandler. So the classloader is happy and finds the AbstractHandler and the WARN message is gone.

As said this is not nice but is a workaround to get rid of the odd messages in the logfile and console. If we are lucky, liquibase may incorporate a fix for this minor bug in 3.4 or maybe in 4.0.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain why this class works? Thanks!

Comment: sure, please check my answer extension

Answer (score -5):

When we deploy our application on tomcat, so simple we need to enable the debug level ERROR for org.jboss.modules in standalone.xml file.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the warning is happening, and turning off all warnings for the package has the disadvantage that future important warnings won't be shown.

Comment: The given warning message is related to Jetty.  So we need to disable it for Tomcat